# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jpaUsersService' как исправить?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-jpa

**Вот репозиторий:**

```
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users,Long> {

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM users",nativeQuery = true)
   Collection<Users> usersAll();
    List<Users> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
    List<Users> findByFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

**Вот интерфейс UsersService:**

```
public interface UsersService {
    List<Users> findAll();
    List<Users> findByFirstName(String firstName);
    List<Users> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

**Вот сам имплемент:**

```
@Service("jpaUsersService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UsersServiceImpl implements UsersService {
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Users> findAll() {
        return usersRepository.findAll();
/
```

**Вот так в мейне вызываю:**

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

     GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
     context.load("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
     context.refresh();
     UsersService service = context.getBean("jpaUsersService", UsersService.class);
```

**Вот логи:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jpaUsersService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087)
    at Main.main(Main.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(
```

AppMain.java:147)

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security ">

    <!-- Directory to scan for repository classes -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="repository"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new_telegram</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>postgres</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>314331</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaData"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>-->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: содержимое applicationContext.xml приложите к вопросу.

Comment: добавил applicationContext.xml

Comment: У вас пакет действительно называется `repository`?

Comment: добпвил репозиторий ,который находится в пакете репозитори

Comment: почему UsersServiceImpl является одновременно и репозиторием и сервисом? добавьте вот это <context:component-scan base-package="<package name>" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в applicationContext.xml `<context:annotation-config />`.

Comment: блин, глупая ошибка:D спасибо большое